# ElasticSearch mapping for dynamic keys for indexing a map

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a sample json which I want to index into elasticsearch.
Sample Json Indexed:

```
put test/names/1
{
  "1" : {
    "name":"abc"
  },
  "2" : {
    "name":"def"
  },
  "3" : {
    "name":"xyz"
  }

}
```

where ,
index name : test,
type name : names,
id :1

Now the default mapping generated by elasticsearch is :

```
{
   "test": {
      "mappings": {
         "names": {
            "properties": {
               "1": {
                  "properties": {
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "2": {
                  "properties": {
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "3": {
                  "properties": {
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "metadataFieldDefinition": {
                  "properties": {
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If the map size increases from 3 ( currently) to suppose thousand or million, then ElasticSearch will create a mapping for each which may cause a performance issue as the mapping collection will be huge .

I tried creating a mapping by setting :

```
"dynamic":false,
"type":object
```

but it was overriden by ES. since it didnt match the indexed data.

Please let me know how can I define a mapping so that ES. doesnot creates one like the above .

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a little confusion here in terms of how we index documents.

```
put test/names/1
{...
    document
...}
```

This says: the following document belongs to index `test` and is of type `name` with id `1`. The entire document is treated as type `name`. Using the PUT API as you currently are, you cannot index multiple documents at once. ES immediately interprets `1`, `2`, and `3` as a properties of type object, each containing a property `name` of type string.

Effectively, ES thinks you are trying to index ONE document, instead of three

To get many documents into index test with a type of name, you could do this, using the CURL syntax:

```
curl -XPUT"http://your-es-server:9200/test/names/1" -d'
{
   "name": "abc"
}'

curl -XPUT"http://your-es-server:9200/test/names/2" -d'
{
   "name": "ghi"
}'

curl -XPUT"http://your-es-server:9200/test/names/3" -d'
{
   "name": "xyz"
}'
```

This will specify the document ID in the endpoint you are index to. Your mapping will then look like this:

```
"test": {
  "mappings": {
     "names": {
        "properties": {
           "name": {
              "type": "string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Final Word: Split your indexing up into discrete operations, or check out the [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to see the syntax on how to POST multiple operations in a single request.

Comment: Thanks @IanGabes for the reply.

Comment: I want to index a map into a single type (which is names in this case),having multiple dynamic keys and values.The keys are dynamic Strings  like  "1","2","3" ......."1000" . The values are Strings like "abc" ,"def"......"xyz" .Can you tell me how can I write the mapping for this ?. Thanks.

Comment: Below link will let you understand my question clearly as the same issue is discussed here as well but they dont have an answer still.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/vrD5BMShwf4/discussion

Comment: For the benefit of everyone else reading this question, its probably best if you describe that you are experiencing this issue when storing a json doc generated using a GSON'd HashMap directly in the question. Unfortuantely, you cannot store/map dynamic keys. Are these dynamic strings unique? If so, you could define them as the document ID. If they are not unique, you are best creating a field for them, something like `"dynamic_field" : "value"`